# How to efficently join 2 tables with left join to get only one result according to field

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables

Registry

```
ClientID  Name  Incube
----------------------
1         Joe    as
2         Jack   gt
3         Jor    ee
```

Deposit

```
DepositID  ClientID Quantum
----------------------------
1                1    100.45 
2                1    34.5
3                1    22.0
4                2    1000.0
```

I want to get only one result, this is
The Name, Incube from table Registry and the sum of all deposits made by that person all corresponfing to a certain ClientID

First I was doing 2 queries

```
SELECT [Name],[Incube] FROM Registry WHERE [ClientID] = 1;
SELECT DISTINCTROW Sum([Deposit].[Quantum]) As Total FROM Deposit WHERE [ClienteID] = 1;
```

then I did a left join to get all things more easy

```
SELECT 
[a].[ClientID],
[a].[Name],
[a].[Incube],
Sum([b].[Quantum]) as Total
FROM Registry a
LEFT JOIN Deposit b 
ON a.ClientID=b.ClientID 
group by a.Name, a.ClientID, a.Incube;
```

How do I filter de WHERE clause? I want to get  all data of ClientID=1, NOT ALL, And the question here is how to only compute only the necessary ClientID and not all the clientsID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something you just need to add the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
  [a].[ClientID],
  [a].[Name],
  [a].[Incube],
  Sum([b].[Quantum]) as Total
FROM Registry a
LEFT JOIN Deposit b 
  ON a.ClientID=b.ClientID 
where a.clientid = 1
group by a.Name, a.ClientID, a.Incube;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3673/3)

The result is:

```
| CLIENTID | NAME | INCUBE |  TOTAL |
-------------------------------------
|        1 |  Joe |     as | 156.95 |
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be `having` instead of `where`?  You can't use `where` as the condition on a field that's in the `group by` (I believe)... Or maybe it's only the summable fields you have to use `having` on.  I always get those confused :<

Comment: @nzifnab Yes, you can. The `HAVING` clause is typically used when you need an aggregate function for filtering. For example you would use the following `HAVING Sum(Quantum) > 100` instead of a `WHERE` because you cannot use an aggregate in a `WHERE` clause.  If you see the demo, you will see it is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, Left Join is not at all needed. Use it only when you need un-matched column as well. Simply inner join will do,

```
select r.ClientID,r.Name,r.Incube,nvl(sum(d.Quantum),0) as quantum
from Registry r,Deposit d where r.clientId=d.clientID 
and r.clientID=1
group by r.clientID,r.Name,r.Incube;
```

[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0272/2)